# javascript algorithm - returning elements in first array which are not present in second

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Hi I am stuck on this algorithm.

Can anyone see why this is not working for all tests:

**Instructions:** Your goal in this kata is to implement a difference function, which subtracts one list from another and returns the result.
It should remove all values from list a, which are present in list b.

my attempt:

```
function arrayDiff(a, b) {
  for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < b.length; j++){
      if(a[i] === b[j]){
        a.splice(i,1 );
      
      } 
    } 
  }
   return a;
}
```

When i pass this to my function it works:

`arrayDiff([1,8,2], [])`  it passes and returns `[]`

When i pass this it fails:

`arrayDiff([1,2,2], [2])`  it fails and returns  `[1, 2]`   it should only return [1]

***UPDATE****
THIS IS THE QUESTION, not sure if that helps?

Your goal in this kata is to implement a difference function, which subtracts one list from another and returns the result.

It should remove all values from list a, which are present in list b.

arrayDiff([1,2],[1]) == [2]
If a value is present in b, all of its occurrences must be removed from the other:

arrayDiff([1,2,2,2,3],[2]) == [1,3]

Comment: Isn't the logic flawed? If you subtract all elements in array2 from array1, `arrayDiff([1,8,2], [])` should return `[1,8,2]`, not `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decrement `i` after splicing the array, since the array got one shorter.

```
function arrayDiff(a, b) {
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
      if (a[i] === b[j]) {
        a.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
      }
    }
  }
  return a;
}
```

Edit: that said, a much more elegant solution to this problem would be to solve it functionally.

```
function arrayDiff(a, b) {
    return a.filter(elem => !b.includes(elem))
}
```

Comment: I thought about this as well (or even a one-liner `const arrayDiff = (a,b) => a.filter( value => !b.includes(value)))` but it doesn't work with the first exemple (empty array). This returns the whole a, not []. But I believe OP's logic is flawed.

Comment: Ya I saw that solution with filter but i already started mine with the for loop and wanted to try with for loop. So, if i understand correctly if this is what i passed in ```arrayDiff([1,2,2],[2])```.  on the first iteration array ```a``` would be [1,2,2] then on the 2nd iteration it would be ```[1,2]``` right if i added ```i--```. Not sure I am understanding

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Array.Filter method.

```
    function arrayDiff(a, b) {
      return a.filter(value => !b.includes(value));
    }
```

Comment: I thought about this as well (or even a one-liner `const arrayDiff = (a,b) => a.filter( value => !b.includes(value))`) but it doesn't work with the first exemple (empty array). This returns the whole `a`, not `[]`. But I believe OP's logic is flawed.

Comment: Why should first example return []? It should return [1,8,2], since there're no items to be removed. Am I missing something? What do you mean by "Substract"?

Comment: Because OP said so. They said `arrayDiff([1,8,2], []) it passes and returns []`, which, as we both said and agree, doesn't make sense and should return `[1,8,2]`.

Answer (score 0):

**with one for loop**

```
function arrayDiff(a, b) {
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(b.indexOf(a[i]) !== -1) {
       a.splice(i, 1);
       i--
    
     }
 }
   return a
}
```

**simple way**

```
function arrayDiff(a, b) {
   return a.filter(item => b.indexOf(item) === -1);
}
```